Apache Beam optimise Firestore Reads python
I have sensor data arriving in pub/sub (protobuf) which is inserted in "pipeline_fstore" as a python dict. The data is arriving one at the time.
In the pipeline, on the "Add Metadata ..." step, I'm reading Firestore data to enhance the received data.
How can I optimize the "reads" on Firestore? Any suggestion?
I'm "GroupByKey" later on a field which is added on "add Metadata", so I can't make it earlier.
Q: When we use "start_bundle(self):", it only applies if the data is grouped before, correct? In this case, the "bundle" would be the individual rows, right?
Thanks
fs_results = (
            pipeline_fstore
            | 'Add Timestamp' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(elem, int(elem['measurement_time'])))
            | 'Window into window_size Seconds' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(window_size), allowed_lateness=beam.window.Duration(seconds=60))
            | 'Add Metadata to the original data' >> beam.ParDo(add_metadata())
            | 'Add Node Position' >> beam.ParDo(add_position())
            | 'Extract siteId as Key' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem.get("siteId", ""), elem))
            | 'Group by siteId' >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | 'Write to Firestore' >> beam.ParDo(FirestoreUpdateDoFn())
        )


I was able to optimize the writes into firestore, using the "GroupByKey" and aplying the "start_bundle" and "finish_bundle" to initiate the bundle batch and write the final batch.
Right now with a window of 15s, I'm seeing batch sizes around 10-20rows, which is inline with the receiving rate of data.
Regarding my question about the "start_bundle", as per my tests I was only able to effectively have the window working when I applied "GroupByKey". Having only "windowing" mechanism was not enough to see the current behavior.
Happy to receive any feedback that improve my code as well and happy to help others to achieve the same.
class FirestoreUpdateDoFn(beam.DoFn):

    def setup(self):
        from firebase_admin import firestore
        self.db = firestore.Client()

    def teardown(self):
        self.db.close()

    def start_bundle(self):
        date = datetime.now()
        logging.info(f"Starting bundle - Firestore ({date})")
        self.batch = self.db.batch()
        self.entries = 0

    def finish_bundle(self):
        date = datetime.now()
        logging.info(f"Finish bundle ({date}). batch size: {self.entries}\n")
        try:
            self.batch.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)

